# Como juntar 2 elementos de una lista en prolog

Tags: prolog

Tengo 2 listas.

precio_fuerte([100,110,95,90]).
plato_fuerte([filete_de_cerdo,filete_de_pescado,pollo_asado,albondigas]).

Lo que quiero hacer es una consulta que cuando ingreses uno de los platos te aparezca tambien su precio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tal y como estás almacenando los platos y sus precios, tienes que obtener la posición del plato en una de las listas y luego obtener el precio por la posición en la otra.

```
plato(X,P) :-
    plato_fuerte(Pls),
    precio_fuerte(Prs),
    nth0(I,Pls,X),
    nth0(I,Prs,P).
```

El predicado `nth0(?Index, ?List, ?Elem)` es cierto cuando `Elem` es el elemento en la posición `Index` de la lista `List`.

Ahora puedes listar todos los platos junto a su precio:

```
?- plato(X,Y).
X = filete_de_cerdo, Y = 100 ;
X = filete_de_pescado, Y = 110 ;
X = pollo_asado, Y = 95 ;
X = albondigas, Y = 90.
```

Preguntar por el precio de algún plato en concreto:

```
?- plato(filete_de_cerdo,X).
X = 100.
```

O preguntar por los platos con un determinado precio:

```
?- plato(X,90).
X = albondigas.
```